# Unexpected do block in function application involving ReadMode what does mean this message?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, block, message, readfile

This function reads a String and concatenates to a txt file

```
adicionaEmListaDeCategorias :: [Char] -> IO() 
adicionaEmListaDeCategorias categoria = do
    file <- openFile ("listagemCategorias.txt") ReadMode
    categorias <- hGetContents file
    let categoria1 = (read categorias :: [Char]) ++ categoria
    hClose file
    file2 <- openFile ("listagemCategorias.txt") WriteMode
    hPutStr file2 (categoria)
    hFlush file2
    hClose file2
```

but I'm receiving this error message:

```
main.hs:190:41: error:
    Unexpected do block in function application:
        do file <- openFile ("listagemCategorias.txt") ReadMode
    You could write it with parentheses
    Or perhaps you meant to enable BlockArguments?
    |
190 | adicionaEmListaDeCategorias categoria = do
    |                                         ^^...
```

Comment: wow I did think I would never see one of those again - you have mixed tabs (line `file <- ...`) and spaces (all others) to intend your code

Comment: @Carsten I really though ghc would have a more specific error message for such cases these days…

Comment: well what can I say - don't know - every editor I know will not mix tabs/spaces anymore - guess it was copied from somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I said in the comment - the issue is that you had intended the first line with a *tab*

this one works:

```hs
adicionaEmListaDeCategorias :: [Char] -> IO()
adicionaEmListaDeCategorias categoria = do
    file <- openFile "listagemCategorias.txt" ReadMode
    categorias <- hGetContents file
    let categoria1 = (read categorias :: [Char]) ++ categoria
    hClose file
    file2 <- openFile "listagemCategorias.txt" WriteMode
    hPutStr file2 categoria
    hFlush file2
    hClose file2
```

but Haskell will give you an warning because you did not use `categoria1` and I think you'll want this:

```hs
adicionaEmListaDeCategorias :: [Char] -> IO()
adicionaEmListaDeCategorias categoria = do
    file <- openFile "listagemCategorias.txt" ReadMode
    categorias <- hGetContents file
    let categoria1 = (read categorias :: [Char]) ++ categoria
    hClose file
    file2 <- openFile "listagemCategorias.txt" WriteMode
    hPutStr file2 categoria1
    hFlush file2
    hClose file2
```

(write the concatenated version)

---

also based on your problem description I think your version will not do what you expected (the `read` will fail and you don't need it):

```hs
adicionaEmListaDeCategorias :: [Char] -> IO()
adicionaEmListaDeCategorias categoria = do
    file <- openFile "listagemCategorias.txt" ReadMode
    fileContent <- hGetContents file
    hClose file
    let newFileContent = fileContent ++ categoria
    file2 <- openFile "listagemCategorias.txt" WriteMode
    hPutStr file2 newFileContent
    hFlush file2
    hClose file2
```

Comment: One should also avoid mixing lazy IO (`hGetContents`) and `hClose`. `fileContents` is not guaranteed to contain the whole file in the above code. It's easier to use `readFile`, I think, for this.